# checking if the plot hit a number or not?

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

How to check for any given number how many times a plot hit that number horizontally and get higher?

I have already tried:

```
  import os
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Payam/Desktop/tesla-stock-price.csv')
df['avg'] = df[['high', 'low']].mean(axis=1)
e=df['avg'].values
x = df['date'].values
y = df['close'].values
z = df['open'].values

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
ax.plot(x,y,'b')
ax.set_xticks(x[::150]);
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.plot(np.arange(len(x)),np.zeros(len(x))+50,'k.')
```

Comment: As you can see I draw two plots and i want to know how many times the line cross the plot and gets higher

Comment: Then, do you want to count how many values in `y` are greater than a specific threshold, say `50`?

Answer (score 0):

Given some test array

```
test_array=np.array([1,6,8,65,4,2,5,8,9,6,4,6,9,0,8,6,4,32,])
```

you can get all indices where the value is greater than a number, say 5, like so

```
print (np.where(test_array>5))
print (test_array[np.where(test_array>5)])
```

Comment: you have misunderstood sir, imagine that i have a plot and i want to check for any given number how many times my plot hit that number and gets higher than that .

Comment: all my numbers are float

Comment: Say you want to check how often your "y" array is bigger than 5, just try np.sum(np.unique(y[np.where(y>5)],return_counts=True)[1])

Comment: i want to check how many times it is higher than a given number not how many number are higher than that .

Comment: You wrote _i want to check how many times it is higher than a given number_. What does _it_ stand for?

Comment: @payam saying it is a plot and not just an array is not precise. The plot consists simply of the points of the array, so in order to find out how many points of the plot are higher than a horizontal line you only have to check how many points of the "y" array are higher than the given number

Comment: have you tried np.sum(np.unique(y[np.where(y>5)],return_counts=True)[1])  ?